# Particle in infinite well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, potential

A simple question :

An infinitely deep one-dimensional square well potential confines a particle
to the region $0 \leq x\leq L$. Sketch the wave function for its lowest
energy eigenstate. If a repulsive delta function potential, $V = \lambda \delta(x-L/2)$, $(\lambda > 0)$, is added at the center of the well, sketch the new wave function
and state whether the energy increases or decreases. If it was originally $E_o$,
what does it became when  $x \rightarrow \infty$?

At the end I'm supposed to do a Taylor expansion but don't know what a typical value for $\lambda$ would be?

**My question**: What is a typical value for $\lambda$ in such a task ?

Comment: Is the new wave function not supposed to incorporate $\lambda$ in it somewhere, for the general case,  rather than you getting caught up in a specific number?

Comment: You're suppose to arrive at a conclusion that is independent of the value of $\lambda$ (aside from it's restriction to positive values).

Comment: The solution is a transcendtal equation $\cot (k L/2) = -\frac {m \lambda}{k \hbar^2}$ and you need to determine the lowest possible k and then from k calculate the min. energy level via : $\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}k^2=E$ derived from the Schrödinger equation and the ansatz $\psi=A e^{i k x} + B e^{-i k x}$

Comment: I now want to do a Taylor series with the transcendental equation ...